# CASE expression in WHERE clause for diferent and

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I use case expression to build where like this?

```
select * 
from table 
where
case 
    when x=y then z= j and t=v
    when x=k then q= p and s=l
end
;
```

I need change where clause depending on the value of x variable.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: it's for an OBIEE sentence. Oracle

Comment: `CASE` ***expressions*** return a *scalar* value, not a boolean result.

Comment: @Larnu: unless the scalar value is a boolean ;) (although not in Oracle)

Comment: Nor is SQL Server, @a_horse_with_no_name (which the question was also initially tagged with). And even if `boolean` as a data type exists it wouldn't return a boolean result, it would return the `boolean` data type and you would likely still need to do `{case Expression} = TRUE` (but that's semantics). :)

Comment: Nope. _If_  the standard SQL boolean type is supported, it can be used as a boolean expression just as well (without the need for `= true`) https://rextester.com/LMJTW39754

Comment: Interesting, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using `OR` is to use nested `CASE` statements:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  CASE 
       WHEN x = y THEN CASE WHEN z = j AND t = v THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       WHEN x = k THEN CASE WHEN q = p AND s = l THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ELSE 0
       END = 1;
```

or you could simplify it to:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  CASE 
       WHEN x = y AND z = j AND t = v THEN 1
       WHEN x = k AND q = p AND s = l THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END = 1;
```

However, you should check whether Oracle can use column indexes or if a separate function-based index is required with these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `or`:

```
select * 
from table 
where (x = y and z = j and t = v) or (x = k and q = p and s = l);
```